# How get data from 3 tables?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables

```
collecton, paymentdata, payment
```

`Payment` table is computed table and it has only one product data

So, `rcvamt` and `restamt` get from payment table

I have following data

Collection:

```
id(PK) clientid company     Client  product     total   note
1      2001     Company1    Client1 Product1    50000   note1
2      2002     Company2    Client2 Product2    60000   note2
3      2003     Company3    Client3 Product3    70000   note3
```

PaymentData:

```
wid(PK)wcid(FK) clientid product    rcvamt  restamt rcvdate     nxtdate   Note
    1      1        2001 Product1   500     49500   10-1-2015   11-2-2015 abc1
    2      1        2001 Product1   800     48700   11-2-2015   12-3-2015 xyz1
    3      2        2002 Product2   1500    58500   5-3-2015    6-4-2015  qwe1
```

Payment

```
id(PK)  wid(FK) clientid    product     rcvamt  restamt
1       2       2001        Product1    1300    48700
2       3       2002        Product2    1500    58500
```

I want to show a report like

```
clientid company    procudt   total rcvamt  restamt rcvdate     nxtdate   note
2001     Company1   Product1  50000 1300    48700   11-2-2015   12-3-2015 xyz1
2002     Company2   Product2  60000 1500    58500   5-3-2015    6-4-2015  qwe1
2003     Company3   Product3  70000 -       -       -            -        -
```

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve the result you want?

Comment: Also: ***which concrete database*** is this for?

Comment: i want get only 1 client+product result, so per client, product can be different and per transaction date and note can be different, so i get one record 2,3 time  i mention my requirement in question.

Comment: its concrete 3 table,

Comment: there is note column in PaymentData, which want to Shaw.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.clientid
, C.company
, C.product
, C.total
, P.rcvamt
, P.restamt
, ( SELECT TOP 1 rcvdate FROM PaymentData AS PD1 WHERE PD1.ClientID=PD.ClientID AND PD1.Product=PD.Product ORDER BY rcvdate DESC)
, ( SELECT TOP 1 nxtdate FROM PaymentData AS PD1 WHERE PD1.ClientID=PD.ClientID AND PD1.Product=PD.Product ORDER BY rcvdate DESC)
, ( SELECT TOP 1 Note FROM PaymentData AS PD1 WHERE PD1.ClientID=PD.ClientID AND PD1.Product=PD.Product ORDER BY rcvdate DESC)
FROM
    Collection C 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment P 
            ON C.clientid = P.clientid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentData PD
            ON P.clientid = PD.clientid
```

But I don't know all the relationships between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. It appears you want an aggregation on the `restamt`, both other fields are the last payment received. I also assume this is SQL Server due to your name. If it's a different db, please provide the

**UPDATE:** Changed to LEFT JOIN to handle client 3 without products, fixed typo in product. SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ad566/19/0

```
SELECT
    c.clientid,
    c.company,
    c.product,
    c.total,
    SUM(pd.rcvamt) AS rcvamt,
    LastPayment.restamt,
    LastPayment.rcvdate,
    LastPayment.nxtDate,
    LastPayment.note
FROM Collection c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentData pd
        ON pd.wcid = c.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            wcid,
            restamt,
            rcvdate,
            nxtdate,
            Note,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wcid ORDER BY rcvdate DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM PaymentData
    ) LastPayment
        ON LastPayment.wcid = c.id
            AND LastPayment.RowNum = 1 -- Get last payment info
GROUP BY
    c.clientid,
    c.company,
    c.product,
    c.total,
    LastPayment.restamt,
    LastPayment.rcvdate,
    LastPayment.nxtDate,
    LastPayment.note
ORDER BY
    c.clientid
```

Comment: thanx Jason W, but it not give me output anything. i get above solution its work.

Comment: I made a few edits to fix the query - had a typo in one of the fields and join should have been left join since client 3 had no payments yet. Hopefully it will work for you. I added the SQL Fiddle showing the correctness: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ad566/19/0

Comment: Also, while the answer from PdrSntsFrrr is accurate, I'd be careful if you have lots of records. Proper indexes could make it fine for smaller result sets, but realize you are running 3 correlated sub-queries causing each query to repeat in every row of your result set.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to your Question could look like this

```
Select Collection.clientid
      ,Collection.company
      ,Collection.product
      ,Collection.total
      ,Payment.rcvamt
      ,Payment.restamt
      ,PaymentData.rcvdate
      ,PaymentData.nxtdate
      ,PaymentData.Note

From PaymentData
Inner Join (Select  wcid
                        ,Max(PaymentData.rcvdate) as rcvdate
                        ,Max(PaymentData.nxtdate) as nxtdate
                  FROM PaymentData 

                  GROUP BY wcid) AS SubSelect ON PaymentData.wcid = SubSelect.wcid
                                             AND PaymentData.rcvdate = SubSelect.rcvdate
                                             AND PaymentData.nxtdate = SubSelect.nxtdate

Inner Join Payment on PaymentData.wcid = Payment.id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Collection ON PaymentData.clientid = Collection.clientid
```

Here the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ad566/13) to prove my Answer.

Comment: thanx WiiMaxx, but it not give me rcvamt,rcvdate,restamt,nxtdate, that field null,i get above PdrSntsFrrr solution its work.

Comment: @Dotnet the result of his and my answer are the same as fare as i can see, but how ever make sure to mark the Answer you are use as "Answer"